# what is the proper way to validate all elements of an array in the query parameters even with 1 element with express-validator?

Tags: express, express-validator

Using `express-validator` version `5.3.0`.

I love the new syntax and I want to validate that a *query parameter* is valid. That parameter can be an array (as in *repeat* parameter).

The issue I have is that when only 1 element is passed, the framework seems to just consider it a string and the error message(s) is(are) a bit cumbersome.

with this configuration:

```js
checkSchema([
{
  foo: {
    in: 'query',
    isAlphanumeric: true,
    optional: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid foo'
  }
}])
```

with the url `http://server/api?foo=bar&foo=not bar` I get the following error:

```
{
  "location": "query",
  "param": "foo[1]",
  "value": "not bar",
  "msg": "Invalid foo"
}
```

which seems correct.

However with the url `http://server/api?foo=not bar` I get the following error:

```
{
  "location": "query",
  "param": "foo[3]",
  "value": " ",
  "msg": "Invalid foo"
}
```

It's not a huge deal, but the `foo[3]` `param` is a bit misleading as technically is either just `foo` or `foo[0]`.

I tried with `isArray: true` like below, but no luck:

```js
foo: {
    in: 'query',
    isArray: true,
    isAlphanumeric: true,
    optional: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid foo',
},
```

But that seems to actually ignore the second `foo` parameter (because technically a string is an array of characters?).
And with the single parameter version `foo=no bar` it shows the error message twice (I assume because the validator fails for both `isArray` and `isAlphanumeric`?)

Comment: Hello! This doesn't sound good. Do you mind filling this as an issue on [our tracker](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues), so I can diagnose it with you, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @gustavohenke I just submitted the issue https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/704

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so, it looks like `express-validator` was updated since then and now provides a `toArray` sanitizer.
So now, I can write the following:

```js
checkSchema([
{
  foo: {
    in: 'query',
    optional: true,
    toArray: true,
  },
  'foo.*': {
    in: 'query',
    isAlphanumeric: true,
    optional: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid foo'
  }
}])
```

And as an added bonus, it will now *always* convert queries with 1 parameter to an array of 1 value.